# Angular - show components depending on multiple criteria with filter component

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, dropdown, alphabetical

Angular - show components depending on multiple criteria with filter component.

The multiple criteria options could be ordered alphabetically and only show components with a specific warning-level. Warning-level should be a dropdown with "error", "info" and "warning".

This is an example of some filter component. The component should have the previous mentioned filter options. Related image: https://0x0.st/z375.png

I have no idea how to build such a thing. I saw some filter components, but those are meant for tables. All advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your logs array

const logs = [
  {name:'log1', kind:'error'},
  {name:'log2', kind:'warning'},
  {name:'log3', kind:'info'},
  {name:'log4', kind:'error'},
];

//The function to filter the array

function filterLogs(logs, kind) {
  console.log(logs);
  return logs.filter(log => {
    return log.kind === kind
  }); 
}

// the value to show somewhere

const stuffToShow = filterLogs(logs,'error');
```

I hope this helps!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple routing for that. Each option would navigate to a new route bound to its component.
`<a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/component-one']>Action</a>`

Checkout this component from the Bootstrap library: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: I don't think that routing is what I want. See the image-link on my post. I want to be able to filter on multiple things, but thanks for the advice.